# How to share VPN and DHCP server across multiple hosts?

Tags: vpn, redhat, dhcp, share

I need to set up a small computer network for what is effectively a satellite office for a business. The small network consists of several workstations and a server. The server machine has two physical network interfaces, one of which connects to the internet, and the other which connects to the workstations. What we want is for the workstations to access the internet through the server's VPN connection to the greater company network.

However, most of the tutorials I have found seem to effectively perform NAT on the VPN connection to each workstation.

What I need is for every workstation and the server to be granted an address on the greater company network using the greater network's DHCP servers and domain controllers, and use their DNS servers too, via the server's VPN (rather than every workstation containing its own VPN client and all of them using an individual VPN connection). I assume that each workstation would still require an IP address on the smaller network too, and possibly a virtual network adapter to be configured - this is all acceptable for us.

Unfortunately my networking knowledge is not great, and so I am not sure what keywords to search for to find tutorials that accomplish this.

All of the workstations and the server use `Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7.4 Server`. I am free to make changes to the system in terms of software network configuration, but I cannot change the network architecture, nor the operating system version, if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think waht you want is a Site-to-Site Ethernet Bridging VPN.
I found [this](https://docs.openvpn.net/how-to-tutorialsguides/site-to-site-layer-2-bridging-using-openvpn-access-server/) in the OpenVPN docs and I think this is what you want.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but from what I can see, that requires certain infrastructure on the other end. That's not something I have control over unfortunately.